# SOAPConnection through fake proxy won't fail

Tags: java, soap, proxy

I'm getting mad with this "issue".

I need to make a SOAPConnection through an http proxy without authentication. Because I have no proxy on my network to test, I've decided to test configuring a fake proxy URL to see how it fails.

My surprise comes when I configured "dummyHost" and "8080" and the JUNit won't fail. The connection is made and the response is OK. I expected to get some DNS or timed out issues to check that my connection is trying to use a proxy.

This is my code to configure these settings:

```
/**
 * Configure the proxy settings.
 * 
 * @param connection
 *            The SOAP connection to be configured.
 */
private void configureProxySettings(SOAPConnection connection)
        throws Exception {

    if (isProxyEnabled()) {

        System.setProperty("proxySet", "true");
        if (proxyHost == null || "".equals(proxyHost)) {
            throw new Exception("No proxy host configured");
        }
        if (proxyPort == 0) {

            throw new Exception("No proxy port configured");
        }
        if (connection instanceof HttpSOAPConnection) {

            HttpSOAPConnection soapConnection = (HttpSOAPConnection) connection;
            soapConnection.setProxy(proxyHost, proxyPort);
        }
    }
}
```

The SOAPConnection implementation I'm getting is:

```
com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection
```

If I debug this class ("post" method). The system properties seem to be OK while doing the request:

```
System.getProperty("http.proxyHost"); //returns "dummyHost"
System.getProperty("http.proxyPort"); //returns "8080"
System.getProperty("proxySet");       //returns "true"
```

I'm doing something wrong? How to check if my proxy settings will work?

Comment: Just an idea: in many proxy-using applications (like browsers), the proxy is bypassed if the target host is on the local network. Perhaps the SOAP framework has some default settings that do likewise?

Comment: Thanks for your idea :-) I used "somehost.somedomain.com" to check if my code fail as expected and results were the same. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think I should test my code in a context with real proxy and no direct Internet conection because I'm not sure it works :-(